# No such Payment_intent

Tags: java, ionic-framework, stripe-payments

We are trying to set up a payment system accepting credit card with payment intents, because it has to be compliant with SCA due to us being in the EU and I was following this tutorial: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents/web. However, when we call stripe.handleCardPayment (or stripe.confirmCardPayment) as shown in step 4 of the docs, it does not work. We only get an error message saying "no such payment_intent", and then the client Secret of our PaymentIntent. We have tried the standard 4242... test credit card, as well as the ones provided at the end of the tutorial. We would appreciate if someone could help us with this problem.

We are using Java on the backend side and Ionic on the client side.

```
this.httpservice.getStripeSecret(this.passedEvent.id).subscribe(secret=> {
      // this.stripe.createToken(this.card)
        console.log("secret from server: " + secret.client_secret)
        this.stripe.confirmCardPayment(secret.client_secret
        )
        .then(result => {
          if (result.error) {
            var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
            errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
            console.log("error")
          } else {
            console.log(result);
          }
        });
    })
```

Comment: `confirmCardPayment` takes a second argument of data which is the `paymentMethod`, you are only passing the client secret. check out how to create a paymentMethod through [here](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/reference#stripe-create-payment-method), or create it manually and pass it